# How to handle back press in Unity?

Tags: unity, android

By back press on Android, I want to close all the open windows first then exit the game, I see everywhere it's suggested to check input key in `Update`:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        if (AreAllWindowsClosed())
            Input.backButtonLeavesApp = true;
    }
}
```

But my issue with this is that it's calling the code in every frame and also may handle a single press multiple times!

Isn't there a single `BackPressed` event in Unity for this simple task?

Comment: Why do you say it would it handle a single press multiple times? GetKeyDown returns true only in the first frame of a press.

Comment: @DMGregory Ah, my mistake. I thought it will be true as long as the key is down. this solves half of the issue.

Comment: Then you can fire your own event from a script of your choosing. Why do you need something new for this?

Comment: @DMGregory Instead of constantly checking a flag to see if back key is pressed, I want the system/unity raise an event telling the subscribers it's pressed. This is nothing we can do ourselves, is it?